# Change FetchType.LAZY to FetchType.EAGER temporary at runtime (Hibernate/JPA) in native query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have following repository method

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM property p JOIN address a USING(a_id) JOIN address pa ON p.post_a_id = pa.a_id " +
        "JOIN section s ON s.p_id = p.p_id " +
        "WHERE p.organization_id = :orgId AND p.name ILIKE " +
        "ANY(SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT('%', UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(:search, ' ')), '%'))))",
        nativeQuery = true)
Page<Property> findPropertiesByOrganizationIdAndName(@Param("orgId") Long organizationId,
                                                     @Param("search") String search,
                                                     Pageable pageable);
```

But it gets LazyInitializationException when it tries to get Section entity

how to dynamically change fetch type of Section enity but with native sql?

Property Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Property extends CreatedDateAuditedEntity {
         @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
         @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
         private Set<Section> sections = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Section entity:

```
@Entity
public class Section extends CreatedDateAuditedEntity {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "p_id", referencedColumnName = "p_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Property property;

}
```

Comment: You could use an EntityGraph

Comment: But after that I cannot convert this peace of query to jpql because such functions doesn't present in jpql

Comment: ANY(SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY(SELECT CONCAT('%', UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(:search, ' ')), '%'))))

Comment: Ah I see you also asked another question to the same topic :-)

Comment: But when I passed @EntityGraph above my method i've got an exception with said that entityGraph cannot be with native query

Comment: Why is Property lazy?

Comment: yep) I am finding another solution  ))

Comment: Cause it's OneToMany

Comment: But how can I make sure that  there's a transaction context available when I access section and how this can help me? Could you please explain

Comment: @Kayaman That's just the opinion of Vlad but depends on your use case.

Comment: @Kayaman It depends on the use case (as always)

Comment: @Kayaman I'm using OR-Mapping for 20 years now (TopLink, EclipseLink and Hibernate). And again if I always need the dependency why declare it LAZY and then use EntityGraph or JoinFetch. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Looks like a hibernate limitation. Other providers might allow specifying fetch hints with native queries, or you can see what they support in SqlResultSetMapping. Short of that, you might try setting up an orm.xml file with this relationship as eager and using a different persistence unit when you need this query

Comment: @SimonMartinelli perhaps you're not explaining your point as clearly as you think you are? Besides, SO is not a forum so we shouldn't be discussing things here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a CustomDialect that extends from the class of the dialect you are using and in the registrar the functions that you cannot use with JPQL in the following way:

```
 public CustomDialect() {
    super();

    registerFunction(
        "func_custom",
        new StandardSQLFunction(
            "func_custom",
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING
        )
    );
}
```

and where do you set the dialect:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="your.package.CustomDialect"/>
```